# Invalid syntax error in view.py in django

Tags: python, django

I can't figure out what i've done wrong here. In my views.py.

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST'
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Not sure if it's just a copy and paste error, but check your indentation, and also line 2 should have a colon at the end of the statement.

Comment: besides checking the indentation, it would be good to know exactly what and where your error is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':   #The colon is missing here
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
        return redirect('home')
else:
    form = UserCreationForm()
return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a colon on the following line

```py
if request.method == 'POST'
```

It should look like this

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current second line needs a `:` statement in the end, so it should be:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```